# OSM - unable to filter Alaska state boundary with osmium

Tags: openstreetmap, osmium

I am unable to get Alaska state polygon when filtering with osmium. Any idea how to debug/solve this?

Info:

- downloaded: http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america-latest.osm.pbf
- trying to filter US states, all work except Alaska
- `osmium tags-filter north-america-latest.osm.pbf r/name=Alaska` or `osmium tags-filter north-america-latest.osm.pbf r/ref=AK` do not produce state polygon in result, but for ie. Nevada and all other states works `osmium tags-filter north-america-latest.osm.pbf r/ref=NV`
- relation exists on web and wasn't changed in last month: https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1116270#map=3/56.61/-130.25
- tried `osmium getid north-america-latest.osm.pbf r1116270` and got empty file
- similar queries work in overpass as expected:

```
[out:json][timeout:2500];
(
 relation["ref"="AK"]({{bbox}});
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

[image]

**EDIT1**

- Tried with planet-210628.osm.pbf same results, so I guess it is something with osmium
- After studying .osm and not just .pbf size, I now know that I get relation 1116270, but it has only one node and 100+ ways, so I get that polygon, but it is somehow degenerated
- working with osmium 1.13.1 on debian 9

**EDIT2**

- After using [pbflint](https://github.com/missinglink/pbflint) it seams that relation has missing ways, not sure how to report this or investigate further

> ```
> $ ./pbflint.linux.bin tmp9.pbf
> ```
>
> error: relation 1116270 missing member way 46113982
>
> error: relation 1116270 missing member way 42394837
>
> error: relation 1116270 missing member way 42394795
>
> error: relation 1116270 missing member way 46113981
>
> error: relation 1116270 missing member way 42394788
>
> error: relation 1116270 missing member way 42394794
>
> error: relation 1116270 missing member way 42394790

**Edit3**

All 7 missing ways are on Eastern Hemishpere, looks like osmium bug https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/42394790#map=4/54.54/177.89

Comment: I don't know why, but some states / Canadian provinces are sometimes missing from the north-America / Canada PBF exports. You can try with a previous export ... or with the planet export. (Since it seems only the border is missing, I personally keep a copy of the provinces borders and replace the sometimes-but-not-always missing ones)

Comment: Good idea, tried with planet-210628.osm.pbf but got the same. But I have found some new details which I will place in Edit1.

Comment: @JGH I have mistakenly thought the problem from extract is also in planet because `osmium getid` requires `-r` to collect all child members of relations. I did not use it at first so resulting exports were equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ways are missing in `north-america-latest.osm.pbf` from `Geofabrik` but are there in `planet-210628.osm.pbf`.
But, when I was debugging this the first time few weeks ago I tried to extract relation with osmium getid without -r argument and incomplete output made me assume that osmium works bad on both america and planet data.

So when I run this `osmium getid planet-210628.osm.pbf r1116270 -r -o Alaska.pbf` result is valid.

[EDIT 1]
More info on [osmium bug](https://github.com/osmcode/osmium-tool/issues/222) which I suspect caused missing ways in `north-america-latest.osm.pbf` and in my data while I was processing it later.